# Can I change a Cordova/iOS app's "displayed name" without changing the entire file structure/Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

So, I working on my first Cordova app, and I've got a probably typical noob question...

I created my app with this command:

```
cordova create MyFirstApp com.[my_domain].myfirstapp MyFirstApp
```

I can see that this creates a complex file structure under a directory named *MyFirstApp*, an Xcode project named *MyFirstApp.xcodeproj*, and dozens of files beginning with *MyFirstApp* (e.g., *MyFirstApp-Info.plist*, *MyFirstApp-Prefix.pch*, etc).

All of that is fine.

But, after finishing development - I realize that I'd like the app's name ***as it appears on the user's homescreen*** to be something different (E.g., "Cool App!").

Can I change just the "displayed name" without making a mess of the directory structure and Xcode project?

It looks like the `name` node in `config.xml` ***doesn't*** do this - that value seems to control much more than just the way the name is displayed. (E.g., if I change it, `cordova build iOS` fails and Xcode starts complaining...)

Comment: Edit `Bundle display name` node in `MyFirstApp-Info.plist`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you make that an answer, I'll set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `Bundle display name` node in `MyFirstApp-Info.plist`.

Answer (score 27):

You can change `CFBundleDisplayName` in your `*-Info.plist` file by adding the following to Cordova's `config.xml`

```
<config-file parent="CFBundleDisplayName" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>My App</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the proper way to keep the change even after removing the cordova platform!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer because it persists the change when `cordova prepare` is run. Otherwise, the changes made to Info.plist are overwritten by Cordova with the application name

Answer (score 16):

You can add a short name to the `name` element in the `config.xml` of your app:

```
<widget ...>
   <name short="HiCdv">HelloCordova</name>
</widget>
```

[Reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#name)

---

Or if the above doesn't work, you can try this instead:

```
<platform name="ios">    
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="CFBundleDisplayName">
            <string>Your Display Name</string>
    </edit-config>
    ...
</platform>
```

Place that code in the config.xml file for the name to persist between builds meaning you don't need to manually edit every time.

Comment: Sean's answer worked on my Windows system but not on macOS. Your answer however works on my macOS system.

Comment: Th edit-config solution worked on my macOS system. Nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the top level of your cordova project
navigate to 
`platforms/ios/[appname]/[appname]-Info.plist`

inside of the 
`<dict>` tag 
there should be an entry like so

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>[The current name]</string>
```

change this to

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>[The name you want]</string>
```

DO NOT include the [ ] ... they are just for demonstration

rebuild your project

Answer (score 1):

This code is work for me: (config.xml)

```
<platform name="ios">
    ...
    <config-file parent="CFBundleDisplayName" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Your Name</string>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```